# Rails-facebooker2, current_facebook_user throw error when facebooks' user is logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebooker, facebooker2

I am using facebooker2 in Rails 2.3.5 (ruby 1.8.6, and there's no possibility to upgrade its version), and the method `current_facebook_user` is throwing a error when the facebook's user is already logged in.

what i want to achieve is that the method `current_facebook_user` returns the facebook user's data when is logged in.

thanks in advance.